# What is the scikit learn Non-negative Matrix Factorisation Coordinate Descent algorithm?

Tags: scikit-learn, matrix-factorisation

What is the scikit-learn Coordinate Descent (CD) algorithm for Non-negative Matrix Factorization (NMF)?

The sklearn implementation of NMF has two different solvers, Coordinate Descent and Multiplicative Update. These are introduced in the user guide ([here](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/decomposition.html?highlight=nmf#non-negative-matrix-factorization-nmf-or-nnmf)) but not described in detail, except to link to the source papers. For CD, the documentation links to Cichoki & Phan+09 (link is broken in current docs, but you can find it [here](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/transfun/E92.A/3/E92.A_3_708/_article)), but there are 5 different algorithms described therein. The sklearn source code (cython) is given [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f69242646d239d89a5713982946b8ffcf9d9/sklearn/decomposition/cdnmf_fast.pyx) but I'm struggling to understand the procedure, and link with any of those in Cichoki & Phan.

Could someone describe (and preferably provide a source for) the CD algorithm used in sklearn?